# Finding the Inverse of an Element in a Given Group

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the inverse of $7+3i$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$.

I do not have a problem similar to this, therefore any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i can't find anything in my notes to help me even find something to try

Comment: see correction, sorry

Comment: With $\mathbb{C}^{+}$ you mean non-zero complex numbers, right? Then $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is more common notation.

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 9):

HINT: If we try the conjugate (as our guess for the inverse) we have $$(7+3i)(7-3i)=49+9=58,$$ but we would really like this product to be $1$. Can we fix this?

Comment: i understand the conjugate part, unsure where to go from where you ended

Comment: Divide by 58. The inverse of $7+3i$ should be $\frac{1}{58}(7-3i)$.

Answer (score 4):

An element of $C^{*}$ is of the form $a + bi$, where we cannot have $a=b=0$.

$a+bi$ is the inverse of $7+3i$ if $(a+bi)(7+3i) = 1$.

Expanding this gives us:
$$7a + 7bi + 3ai + 3bi^{2} = 7a - 3b + (3a+7b)i= 1$$

Notice that 1 is purely real, so we must have $3a+7b = 0$. At the same time, we must have $7a-3b = 1$. Now, all that is left is to solve this pair of equations for appropriate integers $a$ and $b$.